# Create an image out of an svg + divs with bg-image

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, svg

I want to convert some HTML (svg + divs with bg images) to an actual image, and save it to a directory using JS + PHP.

This is an example of the HTML:

https://jsfiddle.net/9k7u32s4/7/

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://svgur.com/i/5x3.svg" alt="">
<div>
  <img src="http://svgur.com/i/5wM.svg" alt="">
  <div class="d1" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/400/250/?image=114)"></div>
  <div class="d2" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/400/250/?image=115)"></div>
  <div class="d3" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/400/250/?image=116)"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

body > img{
  height: 24rem;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}

body > div > img{
  height: 24rem;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
}

body > div{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 15;
}

body > div > div{
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% / 3);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

body > div > .d1{
  top: 0;
}

body > div > .d2{
  top: calc(100% / 3);
}

body > div > .d3{
  top: calc((100% / 3) * 2);
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

And this is how it should look after converting it to an image:

[image]

What is the simplest way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most accurate way would be to build up your image in a `<canvas>` element. You would do this by using `ctx.drawImage` to add dom elements to the canvas and position them (svg's and your background images).

That way you could use `canvas.toDataURL("image/png")` and save it as an image once it was made. That's the JS part. Then once you have the file, save it to a database with PHP.

There are libraries out there like https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ that you could try, they take a dom object and make them into a png, however they're not always the most accurate, as they have to accommodate for all kinds of css selectors etc.

Comment: Hi, I've tried using html2canvas but SVG don't work :/

Comment: Well the problem was that SVG didn't render and allso they masked out all the other things, so I manually draw the SVG after the canvas was made, thanks!